# How to retrieve channel users list with agora.io Unity SDK

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, agora.io

I'm using Agora.io Unity SDK to implement a video chat feature in a game. But I don't know how to retrieve the list of users currently present in the channel. Does someone have an idea how to do so ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please check this article : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Please edit your question by adding more details about your problem and provide code example of what you have tried so far

Answer (score 3):

There is no script to query the list of users in the channel. You will have to keep track of that yourself. It pretty simple.

Within the script where you initialize the Agora engine, create a list

```
static List<uint> remoteStreams = new List<uint>();
```

and then whenever you initialized the engine be sure to include the call back to listen for any remote user that joins the stream.

```
mRtcEngine.OnUserJoined += (uint uid, int elapsed) => {
    string userJoinedMessage = string.Format("onUserJoined with uid {0}", uid);
    Debug.Log(userJoinedMessage);
    remoteStreams.Add(uid); // add remote stream id to list of users
};
```

Once the user has joined the channel, the callback above is called for every existing user in the channel and then again whenever a new person joins.

Comment: The problem is that this won't account for existing users who were on the channel before you joined. Is there a solution for that?

Comment: yes it will. this function gets triggered for all users in the channel whenever a user initially joins a channel that contains other users. This callback will also get triggered when a new user joins.

Comment: Holy Molly you're right! I'd been using the Volume indication this whole time to get the user list!

Comment: What if user leave the channel? How to decreased the number?

Comment: take a look at the LeaveChannelHandler https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/unity/namespaceagora__gaming__rtc.html#aae4178a6fd8d70775be2bbdcf54bd00c